# Workflow List Permissions in copying data

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list

I have a list set up called FE1, the user adds a new item, saves it and the data goes via a workflow into another list FE2.

The workflow  follows

```
IF Current Item:FE1 is not empty Copy Item in Current Item to FE2
```

I set this up so a certain group of users would have access to FE1 but have no access to FE2. However it does not seem to copy data from FE1 to FE2. I have set up users as a test who have access to FE1 and FE2 and the data copies over fine.

Is there something I am missing that would copy data from FE1 to FE2 where the users only have access to fE1?

Thanks

Comment: If it doesn't copy data, what error you get in the workflow history?

Comment: Hi I get Access Denied in Workflow History

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will work or not. But try to do the same using "App Step" in sharepoint Designer workflow 2013.

Using App step you can create a workflow with elevated permissions.
You can find more about app step [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo).